# JQuery copy of div

Tags: jquery, html, duplicates, clone

I am trying to setup a form where based on the value of a select box either 1,2,3,4 that it would show on the page the following code only the number of times that match the value of the select box.

```
<div id='guestDetails'>
            <tr>
            <td>Guest ".$cnt."'s Name</td>
            <td>Guest ".$cnt."'s Address</td>
            <td>Guest ".$cnt."'s Phone</td>
            <td>Guest ".$cnt."'s Email</td>
            </tr>

            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='guest".$cnt."Name' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='guest".$cnt."Address' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='guest".$cnt."Phone' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='guest".$cnt."Email' /></td>
            </tr>

                </div>
```

So if the value of the select is 2 then those input boxes would show 2 times. If the value is changed to 3 then they would be there 3 times. Not quite sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: I've never seen `<tr>` and `<td>` tags used outside of a `<table>` before.  Very odd.  **Edit:**  Also, there are **two** `</tr>` tags after the first row.

Answer (score 7):

The basic approach is:

1) Make a hidden "template" that we will copy, and a container div where we will put copies:

```
<div id='guest_detail_template' style='visibility:hidden;position:absolute'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Guest 's Name</td>
            <td>Guest 's Address</td>
            <td>Guest 's Phone</td>
            <td>Guest 's Email</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='guestName' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='guestAddress' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='guestPhone' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='guestEmail' /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id='guest_details'></div>
```

2) Set up a function that adds a copy of the template to the container. You use the `.clone()` method of JQuery selections to make the copy, fix the style so that the copy isn't hidden, and use `append` on the container (after selecting it) to put the new element at the end.

```
function add() {
    var item = $('#guest_detail_template').clone();
    item.attr({'style': ''});
    $('#guest_details').append(item);
}
```

3) Call the function however many times is necessary, or in whatever context.

4) In order to make the resulting form useful, you'll need to know which name goes with which address, etc. To do that you'll want different names for the `<input>`s in each `<div>` copy. You can do that by using `.find` on the new item to select the `<input>`s, and then calling `.attr()` again, this time using some nested function to make the appropriate changes to the name specified in the template. (Hint: pass the value you currently call `$cnt` as a parameter to `add()`, and splice it in where appropriate.)

Comment: Is there a reason the `<table></table>` tags have been omitted?  Surely this can't be intentional.

Comment: They were omitted because the OP omitted them and I didn't notice while reformatting stuff. :) Should be fixed now.

Comment: that makes sense.. Can you show me what the attr for adding the id of the element would look like?

Comment: ... Do you actually know jQuery and/or javascript? Have you tried reading the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for the .attr() method?

Comment: Everyone isnt an expert. Trying to learn more. Excuse for questions. Thanks for your help

Comment: The point is that the rest of this is better learned by reading documentation, or even trial and error. I can't meaningfully "show what it would look like" without actually doing the work for you. At least trial and error might lead you to a new, but more refined question you can ask.

Comment: BE VERY CAREFUL WITH THIS! Some inputs like checkbox will not send data unless checked, so if you're not using appropriate input names (such as isActive[0]. isActive[1] etc), then you will not be able to piece together the correct grouped values for the checkboxes. So you are forced to use a select box for boolean values which will send a value yes or no.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the select box,

```
$("#number_of_inputs").change(function() { /* value has changed */ });
```

You can get the selected number within the .change callback by

```
Number($(this).val());
```

Then write a function that takes an index and generates your specified markup followed by clearing a containing div and appending the function call to it in a loop.  For example:

```
$("#number_of_inputs").change(function() {
  $("#container").html("");
  for (var i = 0; i < Number($(this).val()); ++i) {
    $("#container").append(generateForm(i));
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your markup could be wrong. You shouldn't put a DIV like that between the TRs.

Here is an approach to copy your input elements:

Add a id, say `guestInputs`, to the TR that contains your input elements.

Add a listener to the select - `$("#selectID").change(methodName)`

In that method, get the number selected by user using `$("#select").val()*1` and use it to loop and create new input fields as shown below.

```
var newRow = $("#guestInputs").clone(); // clone the item
newRow.attr("id", "guestInputsNew"); // change the ID to avoid conflict
$("#guestInputs").parent().append(newRow); // append it to the table
```

Note that you might want to change multiple IDs in the new row before attaching it to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Simply appending the HTML wont work in your case.  The PHP variables would need to be hard coded other wise they'll show up as text.  You will either need to do some AJAX or write all HTML for a template on the servers side then do a bit of JavaScript work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. It is not exactly what you are doing, but I hope you can get the idea how to do it.

HTML:

```
<select id="number">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div id="display_section">
    <input type="text" name="txt[]" value="" />
<div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var append_str = '<input type="text" name="txt[]" value="" /><br />';

    $('#number').change(function() {
        var total = parseInt($(this).val());
        $('#display_section').html(function() {
            var temp_str = '';
            for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                temp_str = temp_str + append_str;
            }

            return temp_str;
        });
    });
});
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/tA4wH/5/

Comment: how then would change the id/name of the input so there is no conflict? name="guest1name", name="guest2name"

Comment: @Nalley try to understand how the Javascript code works, first, and the answer should become obvious. Hint: the inner 'function' is called to create a string with several `<input>` tags chained together, and jQuery then uses this as the innerHTML of the `display_section` `<div>`. So you would need to modify that code so that each appended `<input>` tag has the number inserted in the right place.

Comment: @Nalley: If you use the `input` name like me `txt[]`, you will get an array `txt` in PHP when you submit the form.  So, you don't need to name the input like `guest1name`, `guest2name', `guest3name`,...